# Как можно реализовать свой ImapClient(GemBox.Email.Imap)?

Tags: c#, imap

Как можно проще реализовать `ImapClient(GemBox.Email.Imap)`,если я из всего функционала использую

```
 RemoveMessageFlags
 AddMessageFlags
 ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");
 new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com");
 Connect();
 Authenticate(userName, password);
 SelectInbox();
 ListMessages();
 GetMessage
```

Comment: Чем не устраивает существующий?

Comment: @Monk Тем, что необходимо реализовать свой, вот ивсе)

Comment: возьмите готовый проект и уберите из не лишнее (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)

Comment: А причём тут [tag:wpf] к вопросу?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov действительно,не причем)